# Return HttpResponse from pre_save()

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to find a way to interrupt a save and return a HttpResponse from it. So far I've only managed to do this with raising an Exception, but I want to return a propper HttpResponse.

Any ideas? Also looking for any other ways of stopping a save.

Comment: If this is validation, it belongs in either model or form validation methods, rather than in a pre_save signal.

Answer (score 0):

If you catch that raised exception at the place in your view where you triggered the signal you can then respond with whatever you want in the view.